# How can I click a button on web page using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

URL-

```
<input type="image" src="/live_market/resources/images/gobtn.gif" alt="btn" onclick="goBtnClick('stock');" style="cursor: pointer">
```

I am trying to click the go button.

```
IE.document.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = "ACC"

IE.document.all.Iteam(stock).FireEvent ("onclick")    ' not working
IE.document.querySelector("goBtnClick('stock')").Click 'not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you want is probably:

```
input[type=image][onclick]
```

You can invoke the `onclick` function directly:

```
document.querySelector("input[type=image][onclick]").onclick()
```

Comment: Thank you sir this code is working fine-  IE.document.querySelector("input[type=image][onclick]").onclick